# 404 Error while accessing https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

Tags: java, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

**UPDATE** : 
***As of 29.10.204 5:00 PM EST the services seems to be working fine***

---

We are trying to do authToken authentication and all the request are failing with 404 error.
This started happening since this morning (28-10-2014).

This is happening from Europe (Germany)

**Edit**

Now I am seeing the same behavior from USA as well but the failure rate is less as compared to Germany.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1514)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1508)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, whats going on with: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs . It says "Not found". Any information about this? UPDATE: I just refreshed https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs and the certs were there, another refresh they were gone, now they are gone no matter how many times I refresh the page. What's going on? UPDATE 2: I changed my Chrome VPN to Germany and the certs are there for now, but without VPN, from Croatia, they are not, same message: "Not found"

Comment: Services seems to be ok now

Answer (score 1):

Same issue from Hungary, from DigitalOcean's Amsterdam and New-York region... :/

But, sometimes the reply is 200 and sometimes 404... :(

Comment: There is no answer... it is an issue on the Google side... :/

Comment: Also having same problem from Helsinki, Finland. The weird thing is that if I try the URL in Chrome I get a 200 but Firefox and IE gives me 404.

Comment: Actually seems to be quite random with all the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a workaround! Downloaded the certs, added into my application as static content and rewrite the URL of the public certs. Here is the snippet:

```
final GoogleIdToken idToken = GoogleIdToken.parse(JSON_FACTORY, token);
final GooglePublicKeysManager manager = new GooglePublicKeysManager.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY)
    .setPublicCertsEncodedUrl("http://localhost:8080/static/certs.json").build();
final GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(manager)
    .setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID)).build();
verifier.verify(idToken);
```

It's a workaround, I hope, the Google fix the issue... :(

Comment: I've created an issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/issues/detail?id=913

Comment: Services seems to be ok now